# Mostrar resultados de una búsqueda con AJAX

Tags: c#, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Necesito ayuda con respecto a un AJAX que tengo en mi página, para ser preciso, ese AJAX se encarga de recibir datos del controlador y mostrarlos en la vista según la búsqueda que se necesite, pero al momento de recibir respuesta del controlador no entra al AJAX, se sale y no me muestra ningún resultado. Revisado que envie datos y que el controlador lo reciba y de igual manera envia pero no me muestra nada en la vista.

**Controlador**

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("BuscarCliente")]
    public JsonResult BuscarCliente(string inf)
    {
        List<SearchCustumer_Result> busqueda = new List<SearchCustumer_Result>();

        using(conexion)
        {
            var bsuquedacliente = conexion.SearchCustumer(inf).ToList();

            var asignar = new SearchCustumer_Result()
            {
                IdPersona = bsuquedacliente[0].IdPersona,
                Nombre = bsuquedacliente[0].Nombre,
                Apellido = bsuquedacliente[0].Apellido,
                Edad = bsuquedacliente[0].Edad,
                Telefono = bsuquedacliente[0].Telefono,
                IdPais = bsuquedacliente[0].IdPais,
                NombrePais = bsuquedacliente[0].NombrePais,
                IdEstado = bsuquedacliente[0].IdEstado,
                Estado = bsuquedacliente[0].Estado,
                IdCliente = bsuquedacliente[0].IdCliente,
                Usuario = bsuquedacliente[0].Usuario,
                Correo = bsuquedacliente[0].Correo,
                Contraseña = bsuquedacliente[0].Contraseña
            };
            busqueda.Add(asignar);
        }
        return Json(busqueda);
    }
```

**AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#buscar").on('click', function () {

    var inf = $("#buscarcliente").val();

    var datos = {
        inf: inf
    }
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://localhost:44372/admin/BuscarCliente",
        contentType: "Application/json",
        method: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(datos),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (busqueda) {
            debugger;
            $("#ListaClientes").html(null);
            debugger;
            var html = "";

            $.each(busqueda, function (index, row) {
                debugger;
                html += '<tr>';
                html += '<th scope="row">  ' + row.IdPersona + ' </th>';
                html += '<td> ' + row.Nombre + ' </td>';
                html += '<td> ' + row.Apellido + '</td>';
                html += '<td> ' + row.Edad + ' </td>';
                html += '<td> ' + row.Telefono + ' </td>';
                html += '<td> ' + row.NombrePais + ' </td>';
                html += '<td> ' + row.Estado + ' </td>';
                html += '<td> ' + row.IdCliente + ' </td>';
                html += '<td> ' + row.Usuario + ' </td>';
                html += '<td> ' + row.Correo + '  </td>';
                html += '<td> ' + row.Contraseña + ' </td>';
                html += '<td><button class="btn btn-success" onclick="VerCliente(' + row.IdPersona + ')" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-sm" value="">Editar</button></td>';
                html += '<tr>';
            });
            $('#ListaClientes').append(html);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert("tuvimos un problema" + error);
        }
    });
});
});
```

Donde sale el `$("#ListaClientes").html(null);` está intentando anular el html donde tiene cargada la lista de los clientes y asi mostrar el resultado de la búsqueda.

Dejé algunos debugger para ver su trayecto pero al llegar a `$.ajax` se sale sin poder mostrar datos en la vista.

**HTML**

```
div class="my-4" id="listarclientes">

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
            <th scope="col">Apellido</th>
            <th scope="col">Edad</th>
            <th scope="col">Telefono</th>
            <th scope="col">Pais</th>
            <th scope="col">Estado</th>
            <th scope="col">IDC</th>
            <th scope="col">Usuario</th>
            <th scope="col">Correo</th>
            <th scope="col">Contraseña</th>
            <th scope="col"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="ListaClientes">

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: De casualidad, al poner un breakpoint en el inicio del controlador, ¿la variable `inf` tiene algún valor diferente a null?

Comment: Si recibe la información del value (box de escribir la búsqueda) y el controlador responde y envía los datos todo eso lo he echo pero justamente cuando llega a $.ajax no entra y se sale.

Comment: Click derecho en el navegador, inspeccionar elemento, ve a la pestaña Network y mira si hay llamadas a la URL y si le pasa algo. Por otro lado, quítale el debugger.

Comment: Lo he realizado y si tiene actividad, no se si tiene que ver el método que esta en la misma vista para poder mostrar la lista de Clientes, ese método esta en la @section scripts y se carga al cargar la vista.

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos. PD. ¿Al ejecutar el proyecto, el puerto es el mismo especificado en la llamada en el Ajax?

Comment: Muchas gracias, me servirá para la siguiente, ahora con respecto al proyecto, lo resolví poniendo un input y un botón en la misma vista, gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: En la parte inferior hay una zona para colocar "Tu Respuesta", detalla los pasos y códigos que has modificado para solucionar el caso, de este modo serás el héroe de más personas que les ocurre lo mismo; por otro lado, recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada luego de 24 horas, ayudarás a mantener la buena salud del sitio (efecto de % de preguntas resueltas). Gracias por la cooperación :D